# Error while concatenating plpgsql var with query on cursor statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I am getting error trying concatenate the var sch in the second For:

> ERROR: syntax error in or next a "||"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 1151

Does anyone know how to solve this problem concatenation?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_mallet_input2() RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
DECLARE 
sch name;
r record;   
BEGIN

    FOR sch IN 
     select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('test','summary','public','pg_toast','pg_temp_1','pg_toast_temp_1','pg_catalog','information_schema') 
    LOOP 
         FOR r IN SELECT rp.id as id,g.classified as classif, concat(rp.summary,rp.description,string_agg(c.message, '. ')) as mess
            FROM  sch.report rp
            INNER JOIN || sch || .report_comment rc ON rp.id=rc.report_id
            INNER JOIN || sch || .comment c ON rc.comments_generatedid=c.generatedid 
            INNER JOIN || sch || .gold_set g ON rp.id=g.key
            WHERE g.classified = any (values('BUG'),('IMPROVEMENT'),('REFACTORING'))
            GROUP BY g.classified,rp.summary,rp.description,rp.id
         LOOP

            IF r.classif = 'BUG' THEN
                EXECUTE 'Copy( Values('|| r.mess  || ') ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/BUG/' || quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id || '.txt '' With DELIMITER '' '' ';
            ELSIF r.classif = 'IMPROVEMENT' THEN
                EXECUTE 'Copy( Values('|| r.mess  || ') ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/IMPROVEMENT/' || quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id || '.txt '' With DELIMITER '' '' ';
            ELSIF r.classif = 'REFACTORING' THEN
                EXECUTE 'Copy( Values('|| r.mess  || ') ) To ''/tmp/csv-temp/REFACTORING/' || quote_ident(sch) || '-' || r.id || '.txt '' With DELIMITER '' '' ';
            END IF;             

         END LOOP;



    END LOOP; 
    RETURN; 

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to dynamically change schema for embedded SQL. Any database related identifier have to be constant. If you have some modern PostgreSQL (probably higher than 9.2, works in 9.4), you can change search path:

```
create schema s1;
create schema s2;
create table s1.t1(a int);
create table s2.t1(a int);
insert into s1.t1 values(10);
insert into s2.t1 values(20);

do $$
declare r record;
begin
  for  i in 1..2 loop
    perform set_config('search_path', 's'||i, true);
    for r in select * from t1 loop 
      raise notice '%', r;
    end loop;
  end loop; 
end; $$;
```

If this code doesn't work, you have to use *dynamic SQL* - `FOR IN EXECUTE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, have no PostgreSQL installed now, but it looks like you have to do something like

```
 INNER JOIN || sch || '.report_comment' rc ON rp.id=rc.report_id
```

It treats .report_comment part as a variable or something the other way.

And if the whole script has to be generated dynamically, depending on `sch` value

```
FOR r IN SELECT rp.id as id,g.classified as classif, concat(rp.summary,rp.description,string_agg(c.message, '. ')) as mess
            FROM  sch.report rp
            INNER JOIN || sch || .report_comment rc ON rp.id=rc.report_id
            INNER JOIN || sch || .comment c ON rc.comments_generatedid=c.generatedid 
            INNER JOIN || sch || .gold_set g ON rp.id=g.key
            WHERE g.classified = any (values('BUG'),('IMPROVEMENT'),('REFACTORING'))
            GROUP BY g.classified,rp.summary,rp.description,rp.id
```

then you should call it dynamic way - `execute blabla`, just like you are doing in the code above.

Comment: The difficulty is get schema name in dynamic call using only one loop statement. @miraclefoxx